# app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac task failing, erroring out on its own code

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I'm getting this error after running `npx react-native run-android`, and I'm new to react and node in general so I'm not sure what could be going on.

`gradle build --warning-mode all` runs successfully with no issue. Not sure what could be going on. Running `react-native upgrade` doesn't help as suggested in similar questions, but it does give the error "Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency", though I think it's unrelated.

I'm on npm 6.14.10, node v14.15.4, Gradle 6.4, react-native-cli 2.0.1, react-native 0.63.4, openjdk 14.0.2

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.4/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
106 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 104 up-to-date
/android/app/src/main/java/com/test/MainApplication.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
          return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
                 ^
  symbol: variable BuildConfig
/android/app/src/main/java/com/test/MainApplication.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        ^
  symbol:   variable BuildConfig
  location: class MainApplication
/android/app/src/main/java/com/test/MainApplication.java:59: error: illegal parenthesized expression
    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
       ^
Note: /android/app/src/debug/java/com/test/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

Comment: Have a try by opening the project in android studio and build the Gradle and also try to run from android studio.

Comment: I've tried running to an android studio emulator with the same issue, what do you mean by